# How to use operator in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

```
$a = array("15", "4", "3", "2");
```

to calculate  I use array_sum($a);

how to use minus(-), devide(/) or multiple(*)

I want to 15 - 4 - 3 + 2 = 10

```
$result = 10;
```

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop or [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)?  How do you know which to subtract and which to add?

Comment: You can't using `array_sum()`. I'm not sure how you'd expect PHP to know which ones to add, subtract. divide or multiply.

Comment: $result = $a[0] - $a[1] - $a[2] + $a[3]

Comment: @TylerCollins works in this case but if the array was longer or shorter it wouldn't work

Comment: well as jon stirling asked, how do you expect php to know which ones need to use which operators?

Comment: This is too vague of a question. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TylerCollins well he kind of said what he wants: "_I want to 15 - 4 - 3 + 2 = 10_" :D

Comment: right, but that also "wouldn't work" if the array was longer or shorter.

Comment: I want use loop to add, subtract, divide or multiply.!

Comment: array_reduce with a callback to implement the operator might be a logical approach

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, strings are wrapped in quotes, numeric values aren't.
Secondly, just follow math rules.

```
$a = array(15, 4, 3, 2);  // No quotes around numeric values
$b = $a[0] - $a[1] - $a[2] + $a[3];  // simple math
```

Comment: In this case, they can be strings. They will be automagically cast to ints.

Comment: Yes, they can, but no matter how small an application is it's always good to follow good practice, helps you avoid big mistakes in future on larger projects.

Comment: Sure, IF they were specifically specified in the code. But that's not actually the case, otherwise you wouldn't need to do math on a set of known values ;)

Comment: Cannot disagree with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Using array_reduce() with a callback to implement the operator might be a logical approach, as long as the operator is consistent across all elements in the array (as it is with array_sum()).

For a `-` operator, something like:

```
$a = array("15", "4", "3", "2");
$start = array_shift($a);
$result = array_reduce(
    $a,
    function($current, $value) {
        return $current - $value;
    },
    $start
);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Wl2YNx)